# Django admin - how to make "inlines" collapsible?

Tags: django, django-admin

With "fieldsets" you can make it collapsible by specifying the CSS class "collapse". How to do the same with "inlines"? Thank you!

Comment: "With fieldsets you can make it collapsible by specifying the css class "collapse"" --- HOW?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

currently django does not support collapsible inlines out-of-the-box. [This ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/494) might give you some pointers.

Nevertheless you can easly achive this by adding some javascript to your template. There are numerous plugins out there that can help you achieve this. The way to add a js to a template is overriding a ModelAdmin form with a ModelForm and setting it's Media class with the appropiate js script.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 90):

In Django 1.10+:

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
     model = MyModel
     classes = ['collapse']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.classes

Comment: This is collapsing the entire Inline. How to collapse model elements within it?

Comment: Collapsing part of a model can be done using `fieldsets` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

Comment: After adding `classes = ['collapse']` to a basic inline, the inline disappears completely. Django 2.1

Answer (score 8):

Check out this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1492/), and you just need to include jQuery (already with Django).